# Reading formatted data in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a data set with specific format that I want to read in C and also print in certain format. Here is the format of my data in text file:

```
sample[0][0]=1; sample[0][1]=3;
sample[1][0]=2; sample[1][1]=4;
sample[2][0]=3; sample[2][1]=5;
```

and I want to read this and return

```
  (*inputs)[0][0] = 1;   (*outputs)[0]=3;
  (*inputs)[1][0] = 2;   (*outputs)[1]=4;
  (*inputs)[2][0] = 3;   (*outputs)[2]=5;
```

I was able to write a code that will read my file in just the following format:

```
1 3
2 4
3 5
```

and here is my code:

```
int main() {
FILE *samples;
samples = fopen ("peaks.txt","r");

int arr[10][2];
int i;
int j;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
        fscanf(samples, "%d, ", &arr[i][j]);
        printf("int = %d\t",  arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
```

How do I modify this code to read the format above? Thank you.

Comment: I don't get your question. Is `sample[0][0]=1; sample[0][1]=3;` C code showing the value at `0x0` and `0x1` or the actual string you want to read?

Comment: @Pablo `sample[0][0]=1; sample[0][1]=3;` is the string that OP is reading from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could read in with, for example for the first line of data,

```
fscanf(filein, "sample[0][0]=%d; sample[0][1]=%d;", &arr[0][0], &arr[0][1]);
```

but it is very fragile becaues if the input file is not exactly that then you will get unpredictable behaviour

You could print out with

```
printf("(*inputs)[0][0] = %d;   (*outputs)[0]=%d;", arr[0][0], arr[0][1]);
```

but probably I got the print statement wrong as I don't know exactly what you want your code to do.

Now for lots of data.....

new version... much simpler...D'oh!

```
int a,b;

for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
        fscanf(samples, "sample[%d][%d]=\%d;", &a, &b, &arr[i][j]);
        printf("int = %d\t",  arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

so now you read in the number values from sample as `a` and `b` - but then don't used these value of `a` and `b` - though to write a good program you could check the values of `a` and `b` are equal to `i` and `j` as you expect.

old not working version below

```
char* string_input[100]; // we need this to get the right format for scanf...

for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
        sprintf(string_input, "sample[%d][%d]=\%d;", i, j)
        fscanf(samples, string_input, &arr[i][j]);
        printf("int = %d\t",  arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

so what this does is make a taylor made string suitable for reading in your data line by line...

so for example if `i=8` and `j=1` then `string_input` will be `sample[8][1]=%d;`

Comment: Yes. What I gave is not the actual data. Just a simple example to show the format. I have about 200000 values:(

Comment: @math17 - dont panic - see next edit in a couple of moments

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I tried and got some warnings.

Comment: readingdata.c:16:17: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[100]'
      to parameter of type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        sprintf(string_input, "sample[%d][%d]=\%d;", i, j);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:28: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                           ^~~
readingdata.c:16:49: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments
      [-Wformat]
        sprintf(string_input, "sample[%d][%d]=\%d;", i, j);

Comment: ~~^
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:56: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                       ^
readingdata.c:17:25: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[100]'
      to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        fscanf(samples, string_input, &arr[i][j]);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: /usr/include/stdio.h:250:55: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      fscanf(FILE * __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...) __scanf...

Comment: @math17 --- ok think this is fixed now - and certainly much simpler and better - should have thought of this before.

Comment: Dear Tom. Thank you very much for your help.  With just slight modification in printf, I was able to get the exact form of the data as in the data set. printf("sample[%d][%d]=%d; ",i,j,arr[i][j]); 
The only thing that is not working is the values to the right of the equal sign but I'll work on this part. The most important part was to get the format correct and which now it is. Thanks again!